# How to use Grafana Alertmanager for Prometheus rules?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

The company decided to centralize all alerting on Grafana (Unified Alerting). Alerts are created through the Grafana UI and the internal Grafana Alertmanager is used for routing alerts to the contact points.

I want to re-use the community-based Prometheus rules in various [mixins](https://monitoring.mixins.dev/). Is it possible to do that with Grafana?

In other words, can Grafana either understand Prometheus rule or accept alerts coming from Prometheus itself? Is manually converting Prometheus rules to Grafana expressions the only way?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Grafana can integrate with Prometheus for alerting. While Grafana's alerting system primarily relies on its own expressions and alerting configuration, it can also integrate with Prometheus Alertmanager to receive and route alerts from Prometheus. However, Grafana doesn't directly understand Prometheus rules; you typically need to manually convert Prometheus rules to Grafana expressions for use within Grafana's alerting system. Alternatively, you can configure Prometheus Alertmanager to send alerts to Grafana, allowing you to reuse Prometheus rules without manual conversion.

Comment: The official docs say it cannot receive alerts from other systems: "The Grafana Alertmanager can receive alerts from Grafana, but it cannot receive alerts from outside Grafana, for example, from Mimir or Loki." https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/alertmanager/

Comment: I got the same answer from ChatGPT on first try, btw. When I pointed it to the official docs that said it can't be done, it said the following: "As of my last update, the Grafana Alertmanager, when used within the context of Grafana's Unified Alerting, is designed to manage alerts generated within Grafana itself and does not natively support receiving alerts directly from external systems like Prometheus, Mimir, or Loki. This limitation means that the direct integration approach where Prometheus forwards alerts to Grafana's Alertmanager is not supported"